# select sublists with items that have multiple occurances throughout list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a nested list of integers ranging from 1 to 5 (not really). I want to ensure that each integer occurs at least once in the list, and if one is missing to replace a sublist with a list that contains the missing integer. (I have a full set of possible sublists to choose from.) I'm having trouble working out the syntax for ensuring that the removed list contains integers that have muliple occurances so that I don't recreate the missing integer problem I'm attempting to solve. Here's an example:

```
a = [[2], [4], [1], [1, 2], [1,2,5]]
```

Notice 3 is missing. If I randomly choose the the second or fifth sublist for replacement then either the 4 or 5 will be missing. I need to choose the first, third or fourth sublist, where each of the sublist elements i has a list.count(i) > 1.

Therefore I want to create a new list of viable selection candidates. I believe the solution should look something like this

```
b = [item for item in a if sum(a.count(i)) > 1 for i in item]
```

but Python3 is complaining that

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment.
```

Any suggestions? Note: the algorithm will need to be able to scale to thousands of sublists, but this would rarely happen because the probability of a missing integer in those cases becomes nearly 0.

Thanks for looking!